# Problem with Median Absolute Deviation

Tags: statistics, outlier

I am using Median Absolute Deviation(MAD) for outlier detection. But the problem with MAD is that if 50% or more values in a sample are identical, then MAD = 0 which is not desirable. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: +1 but I’m not convinced that there is a problem. If you define an outlier as being so many MADs away from the median that is repeated over and over, I could be convinced that values other than that repeated value are anomalous. // What would you do upon flagging a point as an outlier?

Comment: @Dave if out of 30 points, let's say 15 points are same, then another 9 points are same, another 5 points are same. The median is one of those 15 points. Would you just want the median(those 15 points) to be recognized as good data and rest other values as outliers? I personally don't want the algorithm to be so strict.
Also, I just want to report which points are outliers.

Comment: I’m not convinced that outlier detection is a worthwhile pursuit (see Gelman: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/06/02/hate-stepwise-regression/), but that’s a valid argument. In your situation, I would suspect three distinct populations, each of which is homogeneous. (There are other options, line a binomial distribution on three trials, but my scenario is reasonable, too.)

Answer (score 0):

If 50% or more of the values in a sample are identical, you'll have to switch to alternative method from MAD or drop values.

"[Alternatives to the Median Absolute Deviation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2291267.pdf?casa_token=XxprPnVjvwMAAAAA:LID0_rbo6QO0h9efuCyKZsRqwHggTC0IBPprk6JfQOJgI3DTIrFJbc1k6TCOgfxl1QqNevmgYNjpr89XJgxkH-iYwBhVbjCShAfNpurPsDgKzsY2Uj4)" paper by Rousseeuw and Croux detail several methods.